# Is it OK that a website is mirroring SO without attribution?

Tags: discussion, legal, ethics

There is a website that appears to mirror content from SO, without attribution. (Perhaps to profit from advertising?)

Not sure it's OK, so I am bringing it to the group's attention

[ScalaTest on sbt not running any tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972284/scalatest-on-sbt-not-running-any-tests)

http://www.anhuiyouxi.com/scalatest-on-sbt-not-running-any-tests/